# What to do when the selected combobox item has been deleted in the data source

Tags: forms, google-cloud-dataflow

I have an issue with the combobox using datasource from the database:

1. The user select a value and then hit the submit button to persist data to the database.
2. The list used to populate the combobox items also editable by the user in another module and a few days later they remove the item which has been selected from the 1st step.
3. When they open the form in the 1st step, the combobox show empty value which is not acceptable by the users.

Should I not allow the user to remove the item in the combobox list in this case or what is the proper method to deal with this? please share your thought.

Thanks in advance.